# Adding a single item to a ListView in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.iOS application with a ListView in a .xaml file that originally populates with around 4000 items (potentially more) from a DB at startup.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"></ListView>
```

The user will make entries in another page of the application while it's open, so I want to add a function in the .xaml.cs file to update the ListView with only that entry so the other 4000 entries don't have to be accessed again.

Setting all the items in a ListView with a `string[]` or `List<string>` is simple with `listView.ItemsSource = myStringArray;`; however, I can't seem to figure out how to add a single item (string) into the ListView. Some answers include using an `ArrayAdaptor<string>` but this is only for Xamarin.Android. How can I add one string into a ListView in Xamarin.iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ObservableCollection<string> data = new ObservableCollection<string>();

// do something to populate data with an initial dataset

MyListView.ItemsSource = data;

// to add an item to the ListView, add it to the ItemsSource 
data.Add("my new item");
```